# Cygwin ratfor installation

Tags: makefile

I want to install ratfor77 on Cygwin (form the Stanford Exploration Project).

I downloaded it, untar it, attribute the good permissions to the folder ratfor77 (chmod -R u+w ratfor77).

But when I want to use the command **make all** I receive this error:

```
make: *** No rule to make target '/ratfor77', needed by 'all'. Arrêt.
```

I verified that all the files needed were in the folder.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The makefile does not follow the usual conventions. Run `make ratfor77`. Several compiler warnings are emitted but the executable `./ratfor77` is generated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem I describe was resoluted by moving the raffor folfer to the root directory of Cygwin.

I had the message above:

```
Done making all in util/tools/ratfor77
```

I'm following a documentation but it do not work :p

But I didn't have the file ratfor.exe.

So I tried your code:

```
make rartfor77
```

And no it's ok.

Thank you very much Mike.

Comment: You are welcome. Note for the future that to reply to answer, you should add a *comment* to that answer, and not post another answer!